# Returning an array without a removed element? Using splice() without changing the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do something like:

```
var myArray = ["one","two","three"];
document.write(myArray.splice(1,1));
document.write(myArray);
```

So that it shows first "one,three", and then "one,two,three". I know splice() returns the removed element and changes the array, but is there function to return a new array with the element removed? I tried:

```
window.mysplice = function(arr,index,howmany){
    arr.splice(index,howmany);
    return arr;   
};
```

If I try:

```
var myArray = ["one","two","three"];
document.write(mySplice(myArray,1,1));
document.write(myArray);
```

It still changes myArray.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

as suggested by the answer below, here is a code snapshot

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
var cloneArray = myArray.slice();

myArray.splice(1, 1);

console.log(myArray);
console.log(cloneArray);
```

Comment: Why double the memory usage for no reason?

Comment: Thanks. Are pointers being created here? I don't get why it's changing the original array....

Comment: the author actually wants the array with element removed ["one","three"], not the removed element ("two").

Comment: @Neverever `myArray` _is_ the array with the element removed. `cloneArray` is a new array with the original contents of `myArray` intact.

Answer (score 50):

You want [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> Returns a one-level deep copy of a portion of an array.

So if you

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three' ];
b = a.slice(1, 3);
```

Then `a` will still be `['one', 'two', 'three']` and `b` will be `['two', 'three']`. Take care with the second argument to `slice` though, it is one more than the last index that you want to slice out:

> Zero-based index at which to end extraction. `slice` extracts up to but not including `end`.

Comment: how does this get upvoted ? It is not giving a solution to the OP problem... the OP wants to call a function that returns the array without one element without modifying the original array.
What you propose is to call a function that will return one element of the array without modifying the original one.
Inappropriate.

Comment: This is wrong, a will be ['one']. Who upvoted this?

Comment: @MedunoyeLaxusGbenga You're thinking of splice, which changes the original array, whereby slice actually returns a copy (though granted, slice and splice don't intuitively go hand in hand, and imo they could be better designed).

Comment: Yes, @JimJam i mistook this section with the accepted on, my bad.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer the question. Array.prototype.slice can only "remove" elements at the start or end of the array. See other answers for an actual response

Answer (score 28):

Use this:

```
function spliceNoMutate(myArray,indexToRemove) {
    return myArray.slice(0,indexToRemove).concat(myArray.slice(indexToRemove+1));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is old, but this approach might come in handy.

```
var myArray = ["one","two","three"];
document.write(myArray.filter(function(v, index) { return index !== 1 })
```

or

```
var myArray = ["one","two","three"];
document.write(myArray.filter(function(v, index) { return v !== "two" })
```

This uses the `Array.filter()` function and tests against either the index being 1 or the value being "two".

---

Now, I cannot vouch for these solution's performance (as it checks each item on the array, Nguyen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466707/5026708) might be more efficient), but it is more flexible if you want to do more complicated stuff and sure is easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ES6 spread feature:

```
let myArray = ['one','two','three'];
let mySplicedArray = [...myArray];
mySplicedArray.splice(1,1); 

console.log(myArray); /// ['one', 'two', 'three']
console.log(mySplicedArray); /// ['one', 'three']
```

Comment: `mySplicedArray` will contain the element removed from the copy of `myArray` (['two']), not the original array minus the removed element (['one','three']). The author wanted the latter.

I think the author would want this:
```let mySplicedArray = [...myArray];
mySplicedArray.splice(1,1);
console.log(myArray); ```   which results in ['one','three']

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const oneTwoThree = ['one', 'two', 'three'] // original array

// `filter()` (like most array functions) iterates over every item in the array.
// Whatever returns true here is copied to a new array (the `oneThree` variable).
// `item !== 'two'` returns true for everything except 'two'
const oneThree = oneTwoThree.filter(item => item !== 'two')

console.log(oneTwoThree) // ['one', 'two', 'three'] — the original, unscathed, array
console.log(oneThree) // ['one', 'three'] — a copy of the original, sans the value you wanted to remove
```

You'd want to do this so you have a **non-mutated** array.

> I don't think performance is as good as something like `slice` + `concat`, but worry about that if it becomes a problem (it probably won't unless you're dealing with tens-of-thousands of elements in an array). Until then, `filter` is really clean.

> Also note that this will remove ALL instances of the element `two` from the array, so make sure you don't have duplicates in your array that might unintentionally get gobbled up by this approach.

Comment: what if you have duplicated item on your array, but you just want to remove one?

Comment: Why would you use `_` as the parameter name? Normally that's for when you don't intend to use the argument, and if you plan to use it you'd give it a name

Comment: These are both good points. In my experience, most of the time when you want to do something like what OP suggested, you aren't dealing with duplicates (e.g. a list of countries or something)—but you are correct it's good to be mindful of.

I also updated the lambda var from `_` to `item` to reflect the correct conventions. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the index of the element you want to remove, you can use slice() and spread syntax:

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
let removeIndex = 2;
let iHateLemons = [...fruits.slice(0, removeIndex), ...fruits.slice(removeIndex+1)]

// your new array
// console.log(iHateLemons) --> ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
// original array still intact
// console.log(fruits) --> ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a new [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy), which adds a `toSpliced` method to `Array` that returns a copy of the array and doesn't modify the original.

When this is implemented, the question can be answered with:

```js
const myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
myArray.toSpliced(1, 1); // => ["one", "three"]
myArray; // => ["one", "two", "three"];
```

As it's currently in stage 3, it will likely be implemented in browser engines soon, but in the meantime a polyfill is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.tospliced) or in [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy).

Comment: It's in stage 4 now and is supported in the latest version of almost all environments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach to splice an element from array without mutating and without making a copy of itself is using filter:

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
elToRemove = "two"
filteredArr = arr.filter( n => n != elToRemove)

console.log(arr) // ["one", "two", "three"]
console.log(filteredArr) // ["one", "three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
document.write(myArray.splice(1,1));
```

why not just use:

```
document.write(myArray[1]);
```

`splice()` modifies the array in place by definition.  See [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) if you want a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reference the index?

```
var myArray = ["one","two","three"];
document.write(myArray[1] + '<br />');
document.write(myArray);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/dHTUj/

Answer (score 0):

I think the neatest way is to create a simple function, and bind the function to the Array prototype if you need global access.

Most of the answers provided to the question are wrong. People confuse returning one element of one array without modifying its content but what the OP needs is to return a clone of the array without one element.

Here's my solution :

```js
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

/* functional */
window.cloneSlice = (arr, start, end) => {
  const _arr = arr.slice();
  _arr.splice(start, end);
  return _arr;
}
// usage
console.log(cloneSlice(arr, 1, 1)); // one, three
console.log(arr); // one, two, three

/* prototyped */
Array.prototype.cloneSlice = function (start, end) { return cloneSlice(this, start, end) }
// usage
console.log(arr.cloneSlice(1, 1)); // one, three
console.log(arr); // one, two, three
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getSubArr = (arr, start, end) => {
    return end > start
        ? arr.filter((_, i) => i >= start && i < end)
        : arr.filter((_, i) => i >= start || i < end);
};
```

This function returns an array which is a sequence of the original array. It's advantage is that it could be used to get a subArray without a sequence located in the middle of the original array.

```
const chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
console.log(getArrInRange(chars, 2, 4));
console.log(getArrInRange(chars, 4, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(myArray.filter(e => e !== "two"));
document.write(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Return new array without mutating original one**

JavaScript arrays has a new method for this purpose: `array.toSpliced()`

```
const months = ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "May"];

//Delete at index 1
const months1 = months.toSpliced(1,1);
console.log(months1); // ["Jan", "Apr", "May"]

// Deleting/Inserting an element at index 1
const months2 = months.toSpliced(1, 0, "Feb");
console.log(months2); // ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]

//months remain unchanged ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a utility to reuse :

```js
const myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

const yourSplice = (yourArray, elementToRemove) => {
  const index = yourArray.indexOf(elementToRemove);    
  if (index !== -1) {
    return [...yourArray.slice(0, index), ...yourArray.slice(index+1)];
  } 
  return yourArray;
}

console.log(yourSplice(myArray, "three"));
```