# Angular ngrx chart/table data

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an angular 5 app with an ngrx store for my widgets which are stored with an backend (socket.io).
This is how my widget looks.

```
widgets: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        type: 'datatable',
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        dataStream: ''
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        type: 'chart',
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        dataStream: ''
      }
    }
```

Every Widget has a startdate and an enddate. I have already some effects and actions for loading, adding and updating the Widgets in my ngrx store and component.
The components are created based on this Widgets and can be a chart or datatable. And each of this widget should get the datastream (columns, rows, datapoins) from the backend.

My question is how can I implement this with ngrx? Should I load the complete data object from the backend to the widget item or what is the best approach for getting the data based on the Widget from my ngrx store.

Comment: How large is each widget and how many widgets are there? Also, how/whom/how often are these widgets updated? The answers to these drive whether you want to devise a lazy vs  eager mechanism.

Comment: @MoMo The amount of the widgets differs. It can be from 1 to 30. The size of the datastream can be really big. For example a table with 60 columns and 10000 rows. Thats why I don´t know how to do that right as.

Comment: And I have to use SocketIO (WebSockets) because I need the ability that the backend can update the clients if the data in the backend was modified.

Comment: So a widget is max 600000 cells? How many bytes avg per cell (ie how many max bytes per widget)? Also, how many widgets DETAILS are visible at a time? Are all details visible at same time or scrollable? The UI also drives best approach. @peter

Comment: Also, please clarify if widget details are edited by clients or elsewhere? If you're socketing client changes are you managing edits optimistically (latest save wins) or pessimistically (check out/in)?

Comment: I think that there is no max amount of cells. It depends on the selection of the client. In some cases it is possible that it is more than 600000 cells. For displaying the widgets I am using a grid component where a user can add and remove widgets. So it can be that the user adds 3 table widgets and 4 chart widgets and so on. All with different configuration which means different data. The tables are all scrollable in some cases I am using ngx-datatable and for the other I am going to implement virtual scroll. Details are edited by the client and I am managing the edits optimistically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter, thanks for the clarifications. There are various ways to do this, however, based on the information you provided I believe the store state, in the context of Widgets and a Widget (of many datastream rows), will nominally be comprised of TWO slices (ie two SETS of reducers)--**1:** A store slice of an array of shallow widget objects where the datastream = null attribute in each, **2:** A store slice of the current datastream being viewed/edited (with a widget identifier/reference), which itself is an array of row objects. I've pseudo'd each scenario below--I'm sure there are more or alternative/better variations. I assume you understand an ngrx store's reactive dispatch->action->effect->reduce flow and won't get into too much detail with that. I also assume your own or your 3rd party components' views get updated/changeDetected when a fresh copy of an object Widget or datastream row is provided (ie: changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush).

1. **Store slice: Widgets (ie: store.select('widgets')...)**: This store slice is an array of 'shallow' (datastream = null) widget objects. The angular component that contains these will dispatch a 'GET_SHALLOW_WIDGETS' action to hydrate the store slice upon instantiation. I presume the 'grid' component you mentioned will handle showing this store slice/array and also can interact with the store for CRUD operations such as 'UPDATE_SHALLOW_WIDGET', 'ADD_SHALLOW_WIDGET', 'DELETE_SHALLOW_WIDGET', etc.
2. **Store slice: Widget Datastream In View (ie: store.select('datastreamInView')...)**: This store slice is the one widget object datastream that is being viewed/edited. It is an array of 'widgetRow' objects where each represents one row in your data table (for a particular widget) which are presumably managed by ngx-datatable and hopefully 'changeDetectable'. Once a shallow widget ('1' above) is opened, the angular component housing your ngx-datatable will dispatch a 'GET_WIDGET_DATA' action to hydrate the array of widgetRow objects (slice: Widget Datastream In View) where each will be used to populate your ngx-datatable rows. Here you have a few choices for memory management:

   2A: Allow browser to manage memory heap and ask server for ALL data for the widget datastream. This isn't necessarily outrageous.  You might find the browser handling 200MB (or more) of data with ease. If the bell curve of your retrieved data is in that range, I believe it's worth a shot. If you believe not:

   2B: Allow ngx-datatable to manage memory and push/pop array for scrolled out of view of rows. This obviously requires store/backend coordination. In other words, dispatch 'GET_PARTIAL_WIDGET_DATA' and pass an identifier to the 'last' row retrieved the previous time a 'GET_PARTIAL_WIDGET_DATA' action was dispatched. Twitter and Facebook use mechanisms akin to this. In this scenario the 'Datastream' store slice will only contain a subset of the datastream at any given time. CAUTION: Since you're maintaining an array, if you POP out the top elements of an array, a NEW array will be returned and you might get severe flickering. Hopefully your ngx-datatable manages this well and you don't have to worry about it. Otherwise, you need to ensure to write the pop in a way to not result in a mutated new array. Not so hard...plenty of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824916/returning-an-array-without-a-removed-element-using-splice-without-changing-th) in SO.

   2C: Manage smooth scrolling yourself as you suggested which is a variation of 2B in case ngx-datatable doesn't provide this.

Finally, since your view can get updated by a server socket.io trigger, here are a couple of scenarios to consider depending on the data the server sends:

1. **server sends 'WIDGET_UPDATED'**: This server msg contains a widget identifier and nothing more. If the widget in the msg is not the one you're editing, do nothing. On the other hand, if it is the one you're editing, you can allow user to dispatch their latest widget edits (optimistically) via a 'SUBMIT_WIDGET_DATA' store action without notifying them. You can also notify user and allow them to discard their edits and issue a 'GET_WIDGET_DATA' to update their data table view.
2. **server sends 'WIDGET_ROWS_UPDATED'**: this server msg is more granular and contains an array of rows that have been updated for a widget identifier. If the widget in the msg is not the one you're editing, do nothing. On the other hand, if it is the one you're editing, then the trigger will dispatch an 'UPDATE_WIDGET_ROWS' which will eventually result a reducer to find those row objects in that datastream array, delete and resurrect them with fresh data and trigger changedetection for the pertinent rows in your ngx-datatable.
3. etc....

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. This clarified many thing for me. But with slice do you mean a store for each. One for the widgets without datastream and one store with the widgets with datastream? If you mean one store for everything and only a selector for each typ than I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: :). I suspect you're already doing what needs to be done. Semantically, look at a store as a (in memory) database. Each select() retrieves the state of a table ('slice') from the database and reducers interact with each table ('slice'). An application has one store who maintains the different slices via their pertinent reducers. Let me know if you have more qs and don't forget to accept my answer if it qualifies. :)

Comment: @Peter, also BTW best practice is for an app to have ONE store where multiple application states/slices (each with it's on select(..) ) are maintained in that store. I suspect you just need to replace the term 'store' with 'slice/state' in your comment. Given that, yes, there is one widget slice and another currentView slice in your ONE store.  ngrx docs have a great example of a store with multiple UI, user info, etc states in one store.  You really don't need more than one store anyway ...

Comment: @peter (3d comment--please read my original answer with minor updates and my previous comments). I reread your response and, to reiterate, the two slices needed in ONE store are:
  Slice One: an array of Widgets each with a null datastream (shallow widgets).
  Slice Two: the ONE datastream you are viewing/editing (array of rows) with a reference/identifier to ONE widget--NOT another array of Widgets with datastreams populated

Comment: Ok I think that I know what you mean. I already have implemented the store like it is in this example https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-ngrx-socket-frontend. They are using a select slice for a selected Item which seem to be similiar to what I have to do. But they have it as attribute in the reducer state. But I am not sure how to do that for my scenario. I am going to read the docs to understand that better. Do you know any good example for this? And again thank you very much.

Comment: After reread your last comment I think it should be a array of datastreams with a reference to the corresponding widget for each datastream in slice two. As I have more than one widget that is displayed and each can has a different datastream.

Comment: I think that I understand now how to do that. My problem was only the wrong use of the term 'store'. I have to import StoreModule.forFeature('widget', fromWidgetStore.reducers) for the widget without data and StoreModule.forFeature('datastream', fromDatastreamStore.reducers) for the data. That is what I mean with store. But how can I get the data items which belongs to the widget with the reference id? Is it correct to use it like this in the component this.store.select(fromDatastreamStore.getEntitiesArray).map(entities => entities[id]) or do I have to do it in the reducer?

Comment: When you click on a widget, you probably open an angular component which dispatches a request to load your datastream. Now the structure/interface/model of that datastream (slice) is something like this:
interface DataStream {
  widget: Widget, //your widget model...
  rows: DataRow[]
}
and
interface DataRow {
  //all column names and types for a row...
}

The two above define your datastream slice/state.

The reducer for this slice will create the state based on the DataStream interface above.
From there it is more a data structures exercise than a store exercise.

Comment: My problem is to understand how to implement the connection between slice 1 und slice 2. I have slice 1 with my widgets which I am retrieving like this this.widgets$ = this.store.select(fromWidgetsStore.getEntitiesArray). For slice 2 the widget should get the datastream which belongs to the widget. Something like this.widgetItem1$ = this.store.select(fromWidgetsStore.getWidgetDataForWidgetByID(widgetId1)) for Widget 1 and same thing for Widget 2 and so on. My main problem is the implementation of the state, reducers and selectors.

Comment: @Peter, yes, to hydrate slice 2 you need to pass a widgetId parm to an Action ctor via the store dispatch (not select()!). Something like store.dispatch(new getDataStream(widgetId)) where getDataStream is an imported Action object with a ctor that needs a widgetId.  ngrx has an eg app showing this. Here's a link where you can find a book by name by dispatching an Action with the book name passed to ctor as a string: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app/app/books
In any case you always store.select a slice by name then store.dispatch actions to hydrate slice in the store.

Comment: I have already seen this example but this doesn´t help in my case. My state has an array widgetsWithouDatastreamForGrid[]: Widget; and an array datastreamsForWidgets[]: Datastream. On starting my app I want to display all the widgets. For this I have a <div ngFor="let widget of (widgets$ | async)">XXX</div> from the widgetsWithoutDatastreamForGrid slice. To get the datastream I need to replace the XXX. This would then looks like <div ngFor="let widget of (widgets$ | async)"><div [data]="dataStreamForWidget[widget]"></div></div>. And this second binding is my problem.

Comment: @Peter, I understand the first ngFor to show widgets. I don't understand the enhanced second ngFor to display details (we're moving away from the store discussion ..). Please clarify, once you click on a widget (in the grid of widgets) what do you want to show?  Isn't it a NEW view with the widget's datastream in a ngx-datatable (and no longer a grid view of widgets)?

Comment: no that isn´t a new view. The widget itself is displaying the datastream. For example I have a chart widget and a table widget which should be displayed at the same time. This is like a dashboard where you have multiple widgets at the same time. That is why I need the second databinding.

Comment: @Peter, OK. So the datastreams show/open on click of widget or already opened in grid of widgets (which seems what you're implying)?

Comment: yes they should be already open. For example I have a view with 4 chart widgets. Each has is own datastream and the client can see all charts at the same time. The first ngFor is for creating this view. So the 4 components with the charts are created. To display the datastream (set chart dataset) I have to bind the it for each widget to the correct datastream of the sore. The only other view is a settings view where the user can edit the widget details (daterange,...) but this isnt my problem.

Comment: @Peter, ok. First, my answer above needs to be modified where slice2 is an array of datastreams and not ONE 'in view' datastream (that's a lot of data?). Second, you ideally shouldn't hydrate each datastream per ngFor loop.  This will result in multiple $http/@Effects calls. Might be better to send one request to backend (via grid component) to get all the datastreams for all widgets by a dispatch(new getAllDataStream(widgetIdArray[]) action on slice2. So just use the first ngFor and show empty widgets for a second until the slice2 array is hydrated when the http call returns.

Comment: @Peter, BTW, from what your suggesting there is no lazyloading at all and you're getting all widgets AND associated datastreams. If you have a $http call to get it all you might not need slice2. In that case you don't show your widget grid at all until $http returns with all data. You just have one slice where datastream = rows (and not null as was presumed) and populated via that one $http call. Now much depends on what your $http apis are.

Comment: I need the datastream slice seperate from the widget slice because the widget has attributes like size and position which should get updated without changing the datastream. I dont want to hydrate with a ngFor loop I want to get the correct datastream from the store which belongs to the widget. I have the interface Widget { id: string, date: any, x: any, y: any } and Datastream { id: string, widgetId: string, data: any }. My State has 2 array Widget[] and Datastream[]. The ngFor loop is for the Widget[]. In this for loop I need to get the corresponding item from datastream slice.

Comment: In one comment I have mentioned that I have tried to do that with map. Something like this.dataStreamforThisWidget$ = this.store.select(''datastreams').map(datastream => datastream.widgetId = currentWidgetId). But I don´t know how to do that correctly and if this is the right way because I think that I have to iterate the datastream array.

Comment: @Peter, if I understand you correctly, you want to create an array of widget ids? If so, a simple way to do it is slightly modify slice1 model to have that. Upon return of your slice1 http call your reducer will loop through widgets array and create/populate an array of widgetIds. So your slice1 model will be two arrays: Widget[]  and WidgetId[]. Again much depends  on your http apis.

Comment: no I just want to get the corresponding Item from the datastream slice 2. They have a parent child relation. The widgets has a ID. And the datastreams has a attribute widgetId which is the id of the widget it belongs to. For creating the view I make a ngFor loop with slice 1 for widget. In this ngFor loop I need to have a component that selects the datastream with widgetid == widgetIdfromNgFoorLoop from slice 2.

Comment: @Peter, in your second ngFor why can&#39;t you implement dataStreamForWidget(widget) to filter your datastream array? Just use a JS filter() that returns the dataStream based on widgetId?

Comment: this is what I am trying to do. I dont have a second ngFor. But I don´t know what the correct way is. Because I don´t want to iterate through the array. I have seen some examples where they have a function in the reducers with let and map operator and than maybe adding distinctUntilChange to only get a update if it was updated for one item only.

Comment: @Peter, I;m referring to the second ngFor in your previous comments. You cant beat a JS filter. Anyway, there are far too many comments and weve strayed from the original question on the store..:)

Comment: @Peter, I'm going to take another stab at this if I understand what you're asking which may be a rxjs question not an ngrx question. You have 2 observables: slice1 and slice2. slice2 can't get hydrated until slice1 is ready. So you need to use the rxjs concatMap operator. pseudo: widgets$ = select('widgets); datastreams$ = select('datastreams); widgets$.concatMap( datsstreans$ ). subscribe( (widgets) => { dispatch(new hydrateDataStreams(widgets)) }); again, this is pseudocode. This way you can hydrate slice2 once slice1 is ready. I hope this helps. Please update your question otherwise.